# OpenCV 3.0 OpenCL UMat hangs in matchTemplate

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, opencl

I'm running OpenCV 3.0 OpenCL on an Intel i5 with Integrated Graphics 4000 and OpenCL 1.1.

When using the matchTemplate function with UMat in its own thread, the thread hangs and doesn't execute any further lines of code. When it hangs, it doesn't throw any errors or exceptions or anything, the tracker thread just returns and Main continues running.

My threading works fine with normal Mat container using matchTemplate, and my detector thread works well with UMat, so I think its related to the matchTemplate function itself and UMat. Does anyone have any ideas on this?

```
   void Detector::trackOCL(UMat imgLast, UMat img){  //tracker function 
         Rect track = Rect(0,0,0,0);
         UMat result_mat;
         if(!imgLast.empty()){
             if(!img.empty()){
                 matchTemplate(imgLast, img, result_mat, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED); //hangs here
                 cout << "Test statement" << endl; //doesn't reach here
             }
         }
         //rest of code to process result_mat
```

Comment: It is definitely running some CL code in the background and there is some bug in the implementation of it, so it hangs. I would report it in the OpenCV issues: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues

Comment: I just added the UMat CL matchTemplate code to main and its working fine. Must be some nuance with my threading. I'm using boost threads and boost bind. I'll keep digging.

Comment: I know, It's been a long time since this question, but did you find the answer? I have the same problem.